# w10 after 1809 update, net dongle not connecting to Windows update, wi-fi does

Tags: networking, windows-update, windows-10-v1809

Yesternight, my W10-64 updated from 1803 to 1809

Since then, when I am using net dongle (Idea Sim, Digisol Dongle), net is working in browsers (ff, edge), but only windows updates is not finding net
error is:
We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're connected to the Internet.

But, when I am using wi-fi, it did download and install some 5-6 updates, but

how to make windows update use my net?

1. searching on net gave tips about w10 having some location feature, in which my connection's router is not identified/ set, I couldn't understand what these are is and there is no solution offerred there.
2. Windows update used to proceed downloading huge files and had exhausted my 1.4 GB daily quota everyday on this net dongle, as it can't be set to metered. So, this problem is still allowing rest of the pc to use net, and is stopping just the windows update from using net, it could lead to a method of preventing huge downloads of windows update through non-metered connections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I noticed that when I connect to net through connection manager software provided by the dongle manufacturer (DiGISOL), then windows keeps on showing "not connected" everywhere and Windows Update is not able to access net throwing the above message.

however when I disconnect in Digisol software and connect to net through windows (clicking on systray icon and then clicking "connect" on my mobile net (idea) details, then windows starts showing "connected" and it can access and download Windows Update.

In the meantime I had once clicked "net reset" also somewhere in the settings, I don't know whether that had any effect. Though, it had not deleted anything in my net adopters.

This has come as a boon, sort of marking net dongle connection as METERED, meaning updates will not be downloaded through it when connected through Digisol software.

When I don't want windows to automatically download anything and exhaust my bandwidth, I will connect through Digisol software, in which entire net works except updates. And once in a day or a week I will connect not through Digisol software and will connect through systray icon, and will download updates.

However, not running Digisol software will mean that SMS wouldn't come and USSD can't be used. So, I tested and found that while connecting through systray icon, windows update works even if Digisol software is kept running (but not connected through that software). With the software running, SMS and USSD problem is also solved.

Thanks.